# no certificate available when enrolling on behalf

Tags: windows, certificate, ca, certenroll

I have one WinServer 2008 Domain controller and a CA server on it.
I log in with the Administrator account and want to request a certificate "on behalf" of a user of my DC.

for doing that, at first I duplicated these certificate templates:

- smart login
- smart user
- enrolment agent

I changed configuration and permission for new templates so that Administrator account can read, write and enrol for these templates.

After creating these new templates and assigning permissions and configuration, from ***mmc*** and certificate snap-in, for user account certificates, and for "*Personal*" section, we requested a new certificate for Administrator account to make it an enrollment agent as shown below:

[image]

then it is generated with no problem and we want to request a certificate on behalf of a user with this new certificate. But, in "Select enrolment agent certificate" and when we click on "Browse" button, we have a problem because there is no certificate to select, as shown below:

there is no certificate available to choose
[image]

I read a lot of documents online but I did not find the reason to solve this problem!

Answer (score 1):

You need an enrollment agent certificate in the local user store (certmgr.msc)/machine store (certlm.msc) to request on behalf of. This is done by setting the signature count on the template.

If the signature count is not 0 you cannot enroll - because you first need an enrollment agent certificate...

1. Set the signature count on the enrollment agent certificate template to 0.
2. Enroll an enrollment agent certificate - dialog will not pop up
3. Set the signature count on another certificate template to 1.
4. Enroll a certificate based on the template in step 3. Dialog will pop up. Select certificate enrolled in step 2. Done

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem too (cannot choose existing enrollment cert).

The solution (maybe):

Check the access to published crl and/or refresh the crl cache on your enrollment workstation.

From elevated command line:

1. Delete the old cache: `certutil -urlcache crl delete`
2. Resync the crl cache: `certutil -setreg chain\ChainCacheResyncFiletime @now`